# Two 3-way switches; each with lead to light

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I have a single switch C, 3-way switches A and B, and 2 lights. One box has A & C with 14-2 power in and 14-2 wire to light from C. A & B are connected by 14-3 wire. Switch B has 14-2 wire to a second light. I want to remove C and wire A & B such that they operate both lights on or both off.

---

I know that running wire between lights will solve the problem. Yes, I can run that wire from attic to basement. However, I was hoping to not have to do that.

Will this answer work?    [3 way switches with switch load at each end](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/139481/3-way-switches-with-switch-load-at-each-end)

Comment: How practical would it be to replace the wiring between the two switch boxes?

Comment: ...or to run new wire between the lights?

Comment: You're going to need at-least 4 conductors between A and B

Comment: Yeah, the answer that you linked is not going to work for you since you don't have enough wires between your two switch boxes to do anything useful here